# How to check the change if there is new data on response by using volley library? android studio

Tags: java, android, api, android-volley

I am working on a chat app by Volley library. I work with Web APIs to store data. When I need to get messages from Web API, I can get them. And also I can post the message informations(sender, content, date etc.) by post method when someone sends message. But I don't know how to code "when anything changed on Web API". I tried to use an infinite loop which checks the data on web API in every 5-10 seconds but when I go to a different fragment, the app gave error. How can it be possible with volley library or with some other webservices(f.e. firebase etc)

**MessageFragment.java**

```
public class MesajlarEkrani extends Fragment {

    View view;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText inputChat;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    ArrayList<Mesajlarim> mesajlarim=new ArrayList<>();
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView textView;






    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mesajlar_ekrani, container, false);
        preferences=getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        toolbar=view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        textView=view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        inputChat=view.findViewById(R.id.inputChat);
        fab=view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.chatRecyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mesajlariGoster(preferences);





        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (inputChat.getText().length()>0){
                    mesajYolla(preferences,inputChat.getText().toString());
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mesajlarim.size()-1);

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Mesaj içeriği boş olamaz.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        //checks the API in every 1 second to see if there is new data
        final Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mesajlariGoster(preferences);
                handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
            }
        }, 1000);


        return view;
    }



    //to show the messages, gets datas form web API and shows them in recyclerview
    public void mesajlariGoster(SharedPreferences bilgiler){
        String url = "https://api.calmeclis.com/messageList.json";
        String sender = bilgiler.getString("username", "unknown");
        final String receiver;
        if (sender.equals("arhanalp")){
            receiver = "alierencelik";
        }else{
            receiver = "arhanalp";
        }
        int a= 150;

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("message_from", sender);
        map.put("message_to", receiver);
        map.put("client_token", "RwdSHZvAtDE9GAW6");
        map.put("message_limit",Integer.toString(a));
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        JsonObjectRequest messageRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(map), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject mesajlar = response.getJSONObject("messages");


                    if (mesajlar.length()!=mesajlarim.size()){
                    textView.setText(receiver);

                    int baslangic_uzunlugu=mesajlarim.size();



                        for (int i = mesajlar.length()-baslangic_uzunlugu ; i> 0;i--){
                        JSONObject mesaj_id = mesajlar.getJSONObject(""+ i);
                        String gonderici = mesaj_id.getString("from");
                        String alici = mesaj_id.getString("to");
                        String icerik = mesaj_id.getString("content");
                        String date = mesaj_id.getString("date");
                        mesajlarim.add(new Mesajlarim(gonderici, icerik,date));
                    }
                        MesajAdapter mesajAdapter=new MesajAdapter(mesajlarim,getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(mesajAdapter);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mesajlarim.size()-1);}
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Hata oluştu, bu sayfayı tekrar yükleyiniz", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(messageRequest);

    }
    
    //to send message, when the fab is clicked, posts the informations(sender,receiver and content) to the web API. Then the web API automatically saves the message datas
    public void mesajYolla(SharedPreferences bilgiler, final String icerik){
        String url = "https://api.calmeclis.com/messageSend.json";
        final String sender = bilgiler.getString("username", "unknown");
        final String receiver;
        if (sender.equals("arhanalp")){
            receiver = "alierencelik";
        }else{
            receiver = "arhanalp";
        }
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("message_from", sender);
        map.put("message_to", receiver);
        map.put("message_content", icerik);
        map.put("client_token", "rn5ZkHxs43TZAfwM");

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        JsonObjectRequest sendMessage = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(map), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                mesajlariGoster(preferences);
                inputChat.setText("");
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(sendMessage);

    }
}
```

Getters,Setters and Constructor

```
public class Mesajlarim {
    String mesajYazan,mesajIcerik,mesajTarih;

    public Mesajlarim(String mesajYazan, String mesajIcerik, String mesajTarih) {
        this.mesajYazan = mesajYazan;
        this.mesajIcerik = mesajIcerik;
        this.mesajTarih = mesajTarih;
    }

    public String getMesajYazan() {
        return mesajYazan;
    }

    public void setMesajYazan(String mesajYazan) {
        this.mesajYazan = mesajYazan;
    }

    public String getMesajIcerik() {
        return mesajIcerik;
    }

    public void setMesajIcerik(String mesajIcerik) {
        this.mesajIcerik = mesajIcerik;
    }

    public String getMesajTarih() {
        return mesajTarih;
    }

    public void setMesajTarih(String mesajTarih) {
        this.mesajTarih = mesajTarih;
    }
```

**MessageAdapter.java**

```
public class MesajAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MesajAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Mesajlarim> mesajlarim = new ArrayList<>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    public static final int sagMesaj = 1, solMesaj=0;
    String sender;

    public MesajAdapter(ArrayList<Mesajlarim> mesajlarim, Context context) {
        this.mesajlarim = mesajlarim;
        this.context = context;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        if(viewType==sagMesaj){
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mesaj_sag_taraf, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }else{
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mesaj_sol_taraf, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

    }




    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            Mesajlarim icerik = mesajlarim.get(position);
            holder.txtUser.setText(icerik.getMesajYazan());
            holder.txtMessage.setText(icerik.getMesajIcerik());
            holder.txtTime.setText(icerik.getMesajTarih());
            holder.mesajLinear.setTag(holder);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mesajlarim.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtUser,txtMessage,txtTime;
        LinearLayout mesajLinear;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
            txtMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
            txtTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
            mesajLinear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mesajLinear);



        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        sender = preferences.getString("username", "unknown");
        if(mesajlarim.get(position).getMesajYazan().equals(sender)){
            return sagMesaj;
        }else {
            return solMesaj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code examples to provide a clear idea of what may be going wrong?

Comment: I added my codes(fragment, adapter codes and also getters,setters and constructors

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I put an if condition in the infinite loop. Only if the view not equals to null, the code inside runnable will work.

```
//checks the API in every 1 second to see if there is new data
        final Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (getView()!=null) {
                    mesajlariGoster(preferences);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
```